# how to find next index in php array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array with mixed index ie int and string values.

ex.

```
['abc'][p][8][5]['amol']['jon']
```

at Certain point i know the need to check index after index 'abc' , whether it is int or string how can i do that?

Comment: Why on earth do you have such a complicated array?

Comment: that is one deeply nested array

Comment: The inner arrays may have mixed keys. Do you want the type of the first value of the array, or what?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

```
function array_key_relative($array, $current_key, $offset = 1) 
{ // create key map $keys = array_keys($array); 
// find current key $current_key_index = array_search($current_key, $keys); 
// return desired offset, if in array, or false if not 
if(isset($keys[$current_key_index + $offset])) 
{ return $keys[$current_key_index + $offset]; } return false; 
}
```

then use is_int() to check int or string.

Comment: function array_key_relative($array, $current_key, $offset = 1) {
        // create key map
        $keys = array_keys($array);
        // find current key
        $current_key_index = array_search($current_key, $keys);
        // return desired offset, if in array, or false if not
        if(isset($keys[$current_key_index + $offset])) {
            return $keys[$current_key_index + $offset];
        }
        return false;
    } this one saved me .

Answer (score 0):

```
next($array);             //> Advancing
is_numeric(key($array));  //> Checking
```

Comment: That's fine if he previously advanced the internal pointer to the "current" element.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment. Accessing the right element is sufficient to move the internal pointer to that position (which makes sense on a second thought).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question right, but as far as I can see its about getting the type of an _inner_ key, not of a _following_ one? If I'm right, this is not a solution for this problem

Comment: `need to check index after index 'abc'`

Comment: @yes123: Is this an answer to my comment? When yes: "I have _multidimensional array_ with mixed index ie int and string values.". As I mentioned, I don't get it completely :X

Comment: @king: yes it is an answer to your comment

Comment: @yes123 next($array); gives element, index required

Comment: @yes123 on that link i get the function

Comment: i am not talking about that link i am talking about your statement `next($array); gives element, index required`. To extract the next key with `key()` as you asked you need to move on by 1 the pointer with `next()`